# ECW files no longer display or open in ArcCatalog or ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, ecw

When I closed and reopened ArcCatalog yesterday ECW files will no longer display in the preview window and will not open in ArcMap.  I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

I have checked supported raster formats and they are still checked.  Have done a repair installation to no effect.

Has anyone else struck this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you recently upgraded to a new version of ER mapper, it is possible that your ArcMap/ArcCatalog has an older version of the ECW libraries although I think it's highly unlikely that libraries were updated overnight.

Another solution could be to check and see if you have ERDAS ECW Plug-in for ArcGIS Desktop 2015 or if you did have it installed then maybe it got disabled.

This Plug-in is a full release product that adds or enhances the ability to read ECW, ER Mapper ERS and Algorithm ALG files in ArcGIS for Desktop. 
http://download.intergraph.com/downloads/erdas-ecw-plug-in-for-arcgis-desktop-2015

If that fails you could try converting your ECW to another format like Jpeg.

Comment: Thanks, the time between closing and opening the programs was only approximately 30 minutes.  I will test reinstalling the ECW plug in for ArcGIS desktop.  Converting to JP2 is not an option.

Comment: Not sure if this is the full explanation so commenting rather than answering: I installed the ECW for ArcGIS Desktop plug-in and ECW functionality has returned to ArcMAP and ArcCatalog.  However, the plug-in was not previously installed so Arc10.4 must have native ECW support which has somehow become corrupted during my closing of the programs.  Thanks @Scobert.

Comment: Too easy! Glad to hear the good news mate

Comment: ECW is a [Supported Raster Format](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm) (as read-only) in ArcGIS 10.4.  @Ozplanman